# SitecoreQuery not working on interface mapping with Glass?

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a interface that is instantiated by Glass using a Glass sitecoreService.Cast method. The interface has a couply of properties I would like to populate using a query but this doesn't work. Using 'SitecoreChildren' attribute does work though.

Here's my interface

```
public partial interface IVergoeding
{
    [SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templateid='1AEE2D9C-1599-4B49-9DB2-FD638969963C']", IsRelative = true)]
    IEnumerable<IVergoedingRegel> VergoedingRegels { get; set; }
}
```

I checked the templateID and that is OK. Any ideas?

Comment: can you try [@@templateid='{1AEE2D9C-1599-4B49-9DB2-FD638969963C}']. You forgot curly brackets

Comment: Looks like Mike Edwards post on this: http://www.glass.lu/Blog/GettingChildItems is actually wrong, since I ran some tests and it should have the curly braces.  Non-curly braces fails to work in my tests.  But possibly older versions of glass it worked without braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I transformed my comment in an answer. Looks like yoo missed curly brackets on SitecoreQuery attribute. Please try bellow code:

```
public partial interface IVergoeding
{
    [SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templateid='{1AEE2D9C-1599-4B49-9DB2-FD638969963C}']", IsRelative = true)]
    IEnumerable<IVergoedingRegel> VergoedingRegels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: if it helps you, please mark it like correct answer. Maybe others have same issue.